# Azure Function to Azure SQL - Performance and Scaling

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that writes to Azure SQL.  It currently reads from a topic but could be changed to read from a queue.  Is there a preference to read from a topic or a queue?

There are 200K messages per hour hitting the topic.  I need to write the 200K messages per hour to Azure SQL.  During processing I regularly get the error "The request limit for the database is 60 and has been reached.".  I understand that I've hit the maximum number of DB connections.  Is there a way to stop Azure from scaling up the number of Azure Function instances?  What's the best way to share SQL connections?

Any other Azure Function to Azure SQL performance tips?

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no well-defined way to achieve this with Service Bus. You may want to play with `host.json` file and change `maxConcurrentCalls` parameter:

```
"serviceBus": {
  // The maximum number of concurrent calls to the callback the message
  // pump should initiate. The default is 16.
  "maxConcurrentCalls": XYZ,
}
```

but it only controls the amount of parallel calls at a single instance.

I would suggest you look at Event Hubs. You get at least 2 bonuses:

1. You can switch to batches of events instead of 1 by 1 processing. This is usually a very effective way to insert large amount of data into SQL table.
2. Max concurrency is limited by amount of Event Hub partitions, so you know the hard limit of concurrent calls.

On the downside, you would lose some Service Bus features like dead lettering, auto retries etc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Mikhail.  Event Hubs with partitioning is working like a champ!!